# Looking for an example of an ideal contained in the union of other ideals, but not in any ideal individually

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I'm looking for an example of the following scenario:

$A, B, C $ are three ideals such that $C\subseteq A\cup B $ but $C\not\subseteq A $ and $C\not\subseteq B$.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 5):

This situation is impossible.  Indeed, suppose you have such ideals $A,B$ and $C$.  Since $C\nsubseteq A$, there is an element $b\in C$ that is not in $A$; thus it must be in $B$.  Similarly, there is an element $a\in C$ that is not in $B$, so it must be in $A$.

Consider the element $a+b\in C$.  This element is not in $A$, otherwise so would $b$.  Neither is it in $B$, else so would $a$.  Thus $a+b\notin A\cup B$, contradicting the fact that $C\subseteq A\cup B$.

Note that we only used the group structure of $A,B$ and $C$, not their ideal structure.

Comment: Great solution.

Comment: Yeah, what I was trying to do didn't even make any sense.